# How to change module timeout in Require.js?

Tags: requirejs

When I am on slow mobile broadband I sometimes get:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: goog!maps,3,other_params:sensor=false_unnormalized2,goog!maps,3,other_params:sensor=false,async!http://www.google.com/jsapi
```

I would like to raise the timeout for similar users as me sometimes using mbb.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

See `waitSeconds` config value from RequireJS docs:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds

Per the docs, the default is 7 seconds. You can set it in your require.config call like this:

```
require.config( { 
  waitSeconds : 30,
  paths : {
      //etc..
  },
```

Comment: Is it possible to *Simulate* requirejs's load timeout error? Without using a throttling proxy or anything fancy like that?

Comment: @Kumar, just create custom loader plugin like that:
define([], function(resource_name, require, load, config){setTimeout(function(){load({})}, 1000}); and load it using "module!".

Comment: @kumar_harsh (for fellow googlers) Chrome has an integrated low bandwith simulation mode. Look for it in dev tools.